# How can I retrieve information from two different tables in a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to develop a DB stored procedure to be used in an autocomplete feature. If the user types "M" I should return people and groups with the name starting with "M".

I would like to do that in a way that the system should need to call only one stored procedure to avoid the cost of calling the DB twice.

My problem is that groups and people are in separate table (I just need their and and ID), this is what I would ideally do:

select ID, Name from people OR group where name like 'M%'

Of course this is not a valid SQL.
I thought about creating a temp table, making 2 selects (one for people and one groups), inserting in this table and returning it.

Is there a simpler/nicer way to implement it or is this the best approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just perform a `UNION ALL`. Two separate queries, a temp table, multiple inserts, and then a 3rd query, doesn't that sound like a whole lot of unnecessary work?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.SearchTwoTables
  @search_argument NVARCHAR(255) = N'M%'
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  SELECT ID, Name FROM dbo.People 
    WHERE Name LIKE @search_argument
  UNION ALL
  SELECT ID, Name FROM dbo.Group
    WHERE Name LIKE @search_argument;
END 
GO
```

Also I assume your `Name` column should support Unicode strings (and therefore be `NVARCHAR`), otherwise you may find an angry person when you mangle their name upon saving...

Comment: `id, name, 'P' which from ... union all ... id, name, 'G'` if you want to tell them apart at the client.

Comment: @user2246674 that's ridiculous. Please don't turn this into an ad hoc SQL vs. stored procedure religious argument; [we have too many of those already](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=query+vs.+stored+procedure+%5Bsql-server%5D+is%3Aquestion). The OP clearly stated they want a stored procedure.

Comment: @user2246674 how is adhoc a simpler/nicer way? if you believe it to be simpler then please post code and explain yourself.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Yes, it sounds like a while lot of unnecessary work, this is the reason I posted this question. Thanks a lot for your help, I will search for "union all" statement to understand it. Once again, thanks :)